# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'xlable'

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

squares = [1,4,9,16,25]
plt.plot(squares,linewidth=5)

plt.title('Square Number',fontsize=24)
plt.xlable('Value',fontsize=14)
plt.ylable('Square of Value',fontsize=14)

plt.tick_params(axis='both',lablesize=14)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is it because of the version of the problem?

Comment: `xlable` -> `xlabel`, `ylable` -> `ylabel`, `lablesize` -> `labelsize`

Comment: You probably just need to spell 'label' correctly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can try like this   :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

squares = [1,4,9,16,25]
plt.plot(squares,linewidth=5)

plt.title('Square Number',fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel('Value',fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Square of Value',fontsize=14)

plt.tick_params(axis='both',labelsize=14)
plt.show()
```

your question is and should be changed to，

`xlable` -> `xlabel`,

`ylable` -> `ylabel`,

`lablesize` -> `labelsize`, spell the `label` right.